# Finding documentation on ArcGIS Server's Tilemap API call?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tiles, arcgis-rest-api

While I was looking in Developer console, for a JavaScript App which was consuming a Tiled Map Service, I saw that it was making calls to an URL like:

https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Boundaries_and_Places/MapServer/tilemap/4/8/8/8/8

When I tried to figure out what this is, the only place where I found some information, is in this Github Ticket: https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/issues/240

According to this comment, this rest end point tells the JSAPI where there are tiles and where there are not.

That comment was back in 2014. Is any public Documentation available on this REST Endpoint?

Comment: I googled "ArcGIS Server's Tilemap API" and found [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgistiledmapservicelayer-amd.html)

Comment: That's a TiledMapService Layer. I'm looking for a tilemap operation on the REST Endpoint.

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information regarding a [TileMap request / response](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/tiled-elevation-service/).

> The recommended method for detecting missing tiles uses a tilemap
>   request, which is currently specific to the basemap and elevation tile
>   services***. It is not yet available as part of ArcGIS Server. This
>   request is available if the service root info capabilities includes
>   the Tilemap keyword, as shown above. The tilemap request returns a
>   JSON structure containing tile presence information for an area of a
>   specific level.
>
> The level, row, and column arguments select the level and the top-left
>   tile location, while the width and height specify the size of the
>   requested area. The response includes the following: a validity flag;
>   a location structure with left, top, width, and height values defining
>   the area; and a data array of size width x height, which contains a 1
>   if the respective tile exists or a 0 if the respective tile is
>   missing. The data array is in row-major order.

*** in my opinion - meaning *esri* content delivery services, not your own basemap/elevation services.

And so on (read the topic, mostly towards the bottom of the page for full reference)

Comment: nice find! This link answers so many questions that I have.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any public documentation for the `tilemap` response.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the link to [arcgis rest api](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/) documentation

And here is the page specific to [Map tile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/02r3/02r3000000pt000000.htm)

Comment: I'm looking for TileMap, and not Map Tile